# Python Condition Statement with For-Loop

Tags: python, optimization

I am attempting to write a single line of Python code for the following:

```
is_valid = False
for single_object in object_list:
  if single_object.test == test:
    is_valid = True

if not is_valid:
  return 'Bad data!'
```

I know that there has to be a way to accomplish this in less code. I mean, it's Python!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
is_valid = any(o.test == test for o in object_list)
```

The `any(iterable)` function returns `True` if any of the values in `iterable` are `True`, and `False` if none of them are. I'm using a "generator expression" to go through the values in `object_list` and evaluate the condition.

Comment: Thanks! The any() function seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Less code is often not better code.

```
for single_object in object_list:
    if single_object.test == test:
        break
else:
    return 'Bad data!'
```

While this is not one line of code, it is less, cleaner code, and is arguably easier to read than `any`. It's also basically the same speed.

The `else` clause on a loop only executes if the loop wasn't exited by a `break` statement.

I think this is just as Pythonic as the one line solution.

Comment: I definitely agree with your statement "Less code is often not better code". Sometimes it's easy to go overboard many times in Python. I never realized that the `else` clause will be called with a `break`. This is great to know!

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy Banks's solution seems to be perfect to me. Nevertheless I would like to present another one. Not in order to be even superior (it is not), but to show alternatives for non-boolean problems, or if it is important to get the very precise object in the list (maybe in order to modify or remove it).

```
valid_one = next((o.test for o in object_list if o.test == test), None)
if valid_one is None:
    # not valid
else:
    object_list.remove(valid_one)
    # or
    valid_one.special_atr = 42
```